# Embedding an Excel pivot table into C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, pivot-table

Does anyone know how I can embed an Excel Pivot table control in a win form application developed in C#?

The raw data for the form would be coming from a SQL Server 2000 database and loaded into a DataTable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't that you can embed the actual Excel pivot table control into your application but you can make a reference to the Excel libraries to manipulate your data then display it in a  DataGridView or other third party control.

Here is a good article on linking to Excel:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302096

Here is my favorite third party Excel like control:
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/

Hope this helps.